# How to check WPF window open or close

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I want to check if some window is opened or closed. If the window is already open ***focus it***. if the window is already close, open the window.

I use this code:

```
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = "") where T : Window
{
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(): Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
}

private void MenuItem1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsWindowOpen<Window>("TestForm")) return;
    var window1 = new Window1 { Name = "TestForm", Title = "Welcome", };
    window1.Show();
}
```

Can you help with this?

Comment: You never said what's the problem

Comment: maybe you could change "I use this code" to "I use this code, but..." =)

Comment: i wont to if  window is open that window focus

Comment: change the IsWindowOpen so it returns a window as null or the existing window, after that in your OnClick event set the window.Focus(); else show a new window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static T IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = null)
    where T : Window
{
    var windows = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>();
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? windows.FirstOrDefault() : windows.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
}

private void MenuItem1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = IsWindowOpen<Window>("TestForm");

    if (window != null)
    {
        window.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        window = new Window1 { Name = "TestForm", Title = "Welcome", };
        window1.Show();
    }
}
```